# React app hosted by Netlify doesn't update unless F5 or reload

Tags: reactjs, netlify

I'm a little surprised there is nothing out there about this that I have found. But just like the title says, I have a React SPA deployed to Netlify. It goes live without error. The only issue is, if the end user has been to the site before, they have to refresh the page to see any changes I have pushed out.

Is there something I need to add to the index file perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser caches the compiled js bundle.

You can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control

One of your options would be to disable it, or set cache expiration to a lower value during the intense development and increase it if/when you deploy less often.

Another option could be to implement some kind of API method to check if newer version has been deployed and trigger a page refresh. (Please be careful not to discard users work, like data filled in forms, during a refresh)

Each have pros and cons.

Comment: I did read through that link but I'm not sure how to apply this. What would be an example of disabling cache in a react app with no backend? Is it added to the index.html file?

Comment: There's no backend, but there should be some server (netlify?) that serves your compiles bundle. Check here: https://docs.netlify.com/routing/headers/#multi-value-headers